# Prevent shutter animation from appearing full screen when using cameraOverlayView

Tags: objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, camera-overlay

I'm using a custom UIView as a camera overlay. Parts of the top and bottom of the screen are hidden and the middle is dedicated to what the camera sees.

My problem is that whenever I turn on the camera, the shutter animation hides the whole screen.

How can I make the shutter animation to be shown only in the dedicated camera area and be hidden by the overlay.